# Why does the Deduction Theorem use Union?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

We have an initial set of premises $S$.

We are given or observe or assume sentence(s) $A$ is/are true.

We can then prove $B$.

Formally, $S \cup \left\{A\right\} \vdash B$.

Shouldn't it be an intersection? Only when we have both $S$ *and* ${A}$ can we prove $B$. Not when we have $S$ *or* ${A}$, which is what my mental picture of what Union is.

Comment: You are "using" $\lor$ in the wrong way ... The set $S \cup \{ A \}$ is **not** a set that is "equal" to $S$ **or** to $A$ but is the set of those objects $x$ that belong to $S$ **or** belong to $\{ A \}$ : $x \in S \cup \{ A \}$ **iff** $x \in S \lor x \in \{ A \}$ i.e.  $x \in S \cup \{ A \}$ **iff** $x \in S \lor x = A$.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The English word "and" has two different senses, with different translations into logic.

When you say you ate soup **and** salad, you don't mean that you ate something that *is* both soup and salad.  You mean you ate a soup, **and** you also ate a salad. Your lunch, then, consisted of the **union** $$\{\text{Soup}\} \cup \{\text{Salad}\},$$ not the intersection.

That is the sense that is being used here.  When you have a set with both $S$ **and** $A$, you have $$S\cup \{A\}$$ which contains  $S$ **and** also includes $A$.

Or consider "I visited France and Japan this summer." You don't mean you visited the intersection of France and Japan; that intersection is empty.

---

Also note that the intersection is clearly wrong here, since $S\cap \{A\}$ is equal to either $\emptyset$ or $\{A\}$, so doesn't contain anything from $S$ other than $A$.

Comment: I never realized "and" is ambiguous until now...